# Make a function wait for a call to finish before returning

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asynchronous

I used to have this code:

```
static generate() {
    var now = new Date();
    return {
        "date": now.getDate(),
        "day": now.getDay(),
        "hours": now.getHours(),
        "minutes": now.getMinutes(),
        "month": now.getMonth(),
        "seconds": now.getSeconds(),
        "time": now.getTime(),
        "timezoneOffset": now.getTimezoneOffset(),
        "year": now.getFullYear() - 1900,
    };
}
```

And this worked ok, but took date from the client, which was a bad thing, so I moved this code to a Node server so it looks like this now:

```
router.get('/generateTime', cors(), (req, res, next) => {
    var now = new Date();
    res.json({
        "date": now.getDate(),
        "day": now.getDay(),
        "hours": now.getHours(),
        "minutes": now.getMinutes(),
        "month": now.getMonth(),
        "seconds": now.getSeconds(),
        "time": now.getTime(),
        "timezoneOffset": now.getTimezoneOffset(),
        "year": now.getFullYear() - 1900,
    });
});
```

The `generate()` function looks like this now:

```
static async generate() {
    var now = await fetch('link/generateTime').catch(e => console.log(e));
    now = await now.json();
    return now;
}
```

Before that I was doing some firebase CRUD like this:

```
export function setLastActiveTime() {
    firebase.database().ref('Users').child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).child('lastActiveTime').set(Time.generate()).catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

So now, I made it work using `async await` like this:

```
export async function setLastActiveTime() {
    await firebase.database().ref('Users').child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).child('lastActiveTime').set(await Time.generate()).catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

But the problem is, I would need to change **a lot** of code, in other places for this way to work.

Is there a way to keep the old `setLastActiveTime()` function as it was, and only change the `generate()` function so it grabs the date from the server, and waits until the async call is done?

Comment: Basically: no. Everything that touches asynchronous code must itself be asynchronous. You'll have to change that code.

Comment: @deceze ok thanks. Would you like to add an answer?

Comment: Not really, I'll close it as duplicate of the canonical answer showing every way to wait for an asynchronous function. "No" isn't worth another answer. ;)